# What is the correct thymeleaf syntax to show this div?

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a spring application, with Oracle database behind. I have a user table in the database.

The users' active state in the database can have three values: -1, 0, 1.

I can access this value from thymeleaf this way: `<span sec:authentication="principal.active"></span>`

I would like to show a div only for the users that's active state is -1.

What's the correct `<div th:if ...>` syntax to check this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

```
th:if="${#authentication.getPrincipal().active} == -1"
```

Watch out however, because depending on the version of `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity` you are using, the access to the authenticated user differs (you might have to use #authentication.principal.active or something of the sort).